# I cannot select certain parts of my board?

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

I have been dealing with this issue for the past 3 hours, and have moved nowhere from this. Very frustrating, considering this is a one credit course. My main issue is that I cannot move some of my board components when I select them. I have tried selecting a box, unchecking all the protected elements, and utilized the selection filter, to no avail. I still have the following error. All the parts that are not able to be selected have the following out of board issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcwFE.jpg

Any constructive feedback/help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try completely ***clearing*** your selection filter, rather than trying to ***use*** it?

Answer (score 1):

If you select by moving the mouse from upper left to lower right you need to completely enclose the object being selected in the selection box. If you move the mouse cursor from lower right to upper left, you only need to partially enclose the object in the selection box.

Also, your part might be locked. That makes it harder to select. If that's what's going on, you need to locate the component in the PCB window and select it there, then unlock it.